# Inserted Pictures Are Now Links

Tags: excel, vba

I am unsuccessfully trying to adjust code that was created by a previous coworker. Currently we use this code below. It is attached to a button on an excel worksheet, this inserts an image into a specified range of cells, it resizes the image then lands on a cell below to type a description. The problem we are having is our template is now being moved from our server to outside locations. So all of the images are now just broken links. I have attempted several adjustments based on other posts, but none have been successful.

```
Private Sub Picture1_Click()
' Select Image From File
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    If .Show Then
    PicLocation = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
    PicLocation = ""
    End If
End With

' Error Check
If PicLocation = "" Then
MsgBox "No picture selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Initialization
Dim TargetCells As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Set TargetCells = Range("B9:H24")

' Error check 2
If PicLocation <> "False" Then
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicLocation)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

' Set image dimensions
With p.ShapeRange
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = TargetCells.Height
        If .Width > TargetCells.Width Then .Width = TargetCells.Width
End With

' Set image location
With p
    .top = TargetCells.top
    .Left = TargetCells.Left
    .PrintObject = True
End With

 ' Close out operations
Range("a25").Select

Set p = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues when switching versions of Excel a few years ago.  My macro now uses `.Shapes.addPicture`  Modified a piece of your code below

```
If PicLocation <> "False" Then
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes.addPicture fileName:=PicLocation, linktofile:=False, savewithdocument:=True
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still not sure where to make that change to make it work. The pictures that are inserted are different every time, so I can't really link it to a set path.

Comment: I would recommend adding a link to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture(v=office.14).aspx) and also telling @them2854 that `Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicLocation)` needs to be changed to `Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicLocation, msoFalse)` to make your answer more useful for OP and others.

Comment: @Masoud good suggestion.  Updated to add details and to allow current code to set left, top width and height.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sobigen ! I had to make a few adjustments to parts of the old code, but so far that has worked!